# Can firebase block user with his new skd? i got 2 blocked users and this error com.google.android.gms signature not valid

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I got that on my `firebase console panel` and this error on my android monitor report :

> background_crash V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: com.google.android.gms
>   signature not valid.

I couldn't find a solution, really hope someone could help me.

[image: Firebase console]

Answer (score 0):

The `GoogleSignatureVerifier: com.google.android.gms signature not valid` error is just spurious logging, you can ignore it.

The crashes you're seeing will be unrelated - if you go to the Crash panel on the left nav you'll be able to see what the core exception is. For example, in this image the crashes are `IndexOutOfBoundsException`:

[image: Crash cluster for indexoutofboundsexception]

Comment: The problem is that the error is not allowing me to run the app, whenever i try to run it, the app crashes and the only message that i recive from the android monitor is

 "com.google.android.gms signature not valid."

what is more strange is that the app was running whitout any problem but now i have that problem. Any other option or solution? any help will be helpfull Thanks!

Comment: Check the full log cat for the crash - there will be something else in there!

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem adding the OAuth redirect URI (provided on the console firebase panel - Auth tab) to my facebook login panel, Product Settings > Facebook Login config.

Still dont understand why that didn't bother it me at the beginning, but later suddenly crush my app.

As @Ian Barber said the error is just spurious logging, you can ignore it.